# ffmpeg not installing after following the official instructions

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, apt-get

I am trying to install `ffmpeg` following [this](https://github.com/adaptlearning/adapt_authoring/wiki/Installing-FFmpeg) list of instructions. That is:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg  
sudo apt-get install frei0r-plugins
```

However I get:

```
No apt package "ffmpeg"
```

and

```
E: Unable to locate package frei0r-plugins
```

respectively when I run `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg` and `sudo apt-get install frei0r-plugins`. It is worth noting that I get a lot of errors when I do `sudo apt-get update` that look like:

```
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy Release                                                                                                                                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]

E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I am using lubuntu 0.14.1. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Why do you call those instructions "official"?

Comment: Because they are the standard way of installing packs. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Your repository links appear to be incorrect

It seems that you are using (L)Ubuntu 19.04 Disco Dingo. Your repository links look wrong. They show `saucy` instead of the expected `disco`. Saucy is the code name for Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander. Support ended for this version on 2014-07-17. The Saucy repository has been deactivated so you can't install anything from it.

See [How can I find the version of Ubuntu that is installed?](https://askubuntu.com/q/12493) to check your Ubuntu version.

## But Disco is dead

Support ended for Ubuntu 19.04 Disco Dingo on 2020-01-23. The Disco repository has been deactivated so you can't install anything from it.

Consider updating to Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa which is a Long Term Support (LTS) release which has standard support until 2025-04 and security maintenance until 2030-04.

## If you need `ffmpeg` now

You can download it from [johnvansickle.com](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/). See [installation instructions](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/faq/) for more info.

Comment: Ilogan, Thanks for your answer. I get my ubuntu from https://lubuntu.net/downloads/ I thought those would be up-to-date.

Comment: @mm_ That link does provide up-to-date versions. But the info you provided makes it look like your Lubuntu is old. Run the command `lsb_release -a` as shown in the 2nd link in my answer. What is the output from this command?

Comment: The result is: No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:        19.04
Codename:       disco